# How to categorize users based on their movie views?

Tags: statistics, classification

I have a dataset of size `(61573, 25)`. The rows represent `users` whereas the columns represent `views` on particular movie genres. For example, if `data[i,j] == 3` that means that user `i` has viewed 3 movies of gender `j` in total. As expected ,rows are sparse and right-skewed.

What I would like to do is to compute how much engaged a user is on each of the 25 movie genders by assigning to him one of the following tags: {VL, L, A, H, VH}.

What I have tried so far is to compute z-scores, either row or column -wise (I haven't tried to standardize values twice, though (i.e. first on rows and then on columns)), and then apply the following function depending on how far away the z-scores are from 0:

- (-oo, -2] --> VL
- (-2, -1] --> L
- (-1, +1) --> A
- [+1, +2) --> H
- [+2, +oo) --> VH

In either case, my problem is that the results seem very bad in most of the cases probably because they are laying between -1 and +1, and thus are almost always marked as `A` (i.e. average). So, what else should I try based on your opinion? How would YOU approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe most movie goers are average?

Comment: No, I don't think this is the problem. What I think is that I either I am missing something very important (i.e. the idea about z-scores is totally wrong) or I simply have to do some fine tuning (but don't know how to do it...).

Comment: I don't see a reason compute some kind of score. Why not use the numbers as they are? Count = 0 means no interest, anything > 0 means some interest, with interest proportional to the count.

Comment: @RobertDodier the reason this will not work is simply because the scores are relative to the gender category as well as the user, which means that some users tend to watch a lot more movies that others and some genres are get watched by a lot more people that some others.

Answer (score 0):

The z-scores clearly are not the right way to go.

The reason is that they are based on the assumption that your data is *normal distributed*. I have strong doubts that your data is normal distributed - in particular, it probably doesn't have any negative values, does it?

Have you tried just using quantiles? top 10%, bottom 10% etc.?

Comment: Hi! Of course they don't! In fact, the min value if 0 and the max value is around 140. That's why I used the scipy.stats.mstats.zscore()function of Python which I think is appropriate for these cases, doesn't it? Regarding your suggestion, can you please evolve? Would you apply it on rows or om columns? What about the other intervals? Are these percentages an assumption or there is an algorithm that optimizes the cut-offs?